# visual studio 2010 system.management.automation assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, powershell

Been having trouble with visual studio 2010

I've added reference to the project and double checked the 
when i type using System.Management.Automation;
at the top of the file.

when I go to compile / build it ..
it says that the infamous are you missing an assembly reference.
any ideas?

Comment: I can't repro this.  I have added a reference to Sys.Mngmnt.Automation from the Program Files\Reference Assemblies\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 dir, built a small test app and it compiles and runs fine on VS2010 Beta 2.

Comment: Could you post your .csproj file for the project?

Comment: yeah ...
    [SCRNetworkFailure.csproj](http://cs-sol.swan.ac.uk/~cs440361/SCRNetworkFailure.csproj.txt)

ah i've only got the beta 1 ill try updating and let you know

Answer (score 1):

I have had all sorts of issues with System.Management.Automation over time.  I recently hit it again and decided to find an alternative way to run PowerShell from .NET using a batch file.  See this blog post for code samples:
http://www.nootn.com.au/2013/01/run-powershell-from-net-program-without.html

This also mentions how to get System.Management.Automation working; I.e. install a windows SDK and hack the csproject file so it has:

```
<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />
```

I hope this helps solve your issue or work around it!

Comment: Thanks for your imput, this was for a prior employment position so not relevant to me now but if it helps some one else.. Great!! :)